# Generate migration files from exsiting database structure Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, database-migration

I have a system made with Laravel. As we know, we can make database migrations in Laravel using `php artisan`.

So bacially, you create a migration file then edit it for the structure like tables and fields then run the migration command and it will create the database tables for you.

Question, is it possbile to the reverse? I have already an exisiting database with tables in it and already structured. Is there something I can do to to generate all the migration files needed for that without doing it manually for each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, have a look at:

https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator

This works quite well, used it a few times on projects I've inherited from other developers.

Works with Laravel 5 too.